# How unique field on SQL Server allow duplicate values from different item brand names

Tags: vb.net

I'm designing an app for stock keeping. In my database, I have a field called `ItemSerialNo` and I made it unique(but not the table's primary key). On my front end, I have a text box for Item Serial No and a combo box loaded with the item brands and also a save button. I know that if I try to save a serial no already existing in my database, the app won't allow me because of the unique property of the field named `ItemSerialNo`.

But I want to be able to save a serial no already existing in my DB but with a different brand name.

For example, I want to be able to save information like:

1. ITEM SERIAL NO = 12345
   BRAND NAME = AA
2. ITEM SERIAL NO = 12345
   BRAND NAME = BB.

Comment: This is nothing to do with your front end application.  You need to change your database to allow that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not with a unique constraint on your "ItemSerialNo" column. You would need to change the database to have a compond unique constraint including both fields. Then you can duplicate either field but not the combination of both of them.

Comment: composite key, is what we call them